# How to Dynamically hide element for currentuser?

Tags: angular, typescript, parse-platform, ionic2

So I have a list of people that a user is following. I want to make it so that when the current user is viewing a guest user's follow. The button to follow the current user is removed. This is my attempt below.

Edit: when I run the code like this, all users show the button and show the following. It does not hide for current user.

HTML Code:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Follow</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let pic of pics" (click)="viewGuest(pic.user)">
    <ion-thumbnail item-left>
      <img src="{{pic.avi['url']}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{pic.additional}}</h2>
    <p>{{pic.user}}</p>
    <div [ngSwitch]="value" item-right>
      <span *ngSwitchCase="false">
        <span [ngSwitch]="connect">
          <span *ngSwitchCase="false"> 
            <button ion-button>Follow</button>
          </span>
          <span *ngSwitchDefault>
            <button ion-button>Following</button>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span *ngSwitchDefault></span>
    </div>
  </button>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GuestPage} from '../guest/guest'
var Parse = require('parse');

@Component({
  selector: 'page-follow',
  templateUrl: 'follow.html'
})
export class FollowPage {

  follows = []
  pics = []
  parameter1 = ''
  passedUser = ''
  value = false
  connection = false

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    Parse.initialize('hidden','unused', "hidden");
    Parse.serverURL = 'hidden';
    this.parameter1 = navParams.get('param1')
    this.passedUser = navParams.get('userParam')
  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    if (this.parameter1 == "Followers"){
    this.initializeFollowers()
  } else{
    this.initializeFollowing()
  }

  if (this.follows == Parse.User.current().get("username")){
    this.value = true
  } else{
    this.value = false
  }




  console.log(this.parameter1);
  }

  ionViewDidLeave(){
    this.follows.length = 0
    this.pics.length = 0
    this.parameter1=''
  }

  initializeFollowers() {
    var this_ref = this
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current().get("username");
    var Follower = Parse.Object.extend("Follow")
    var query = new Parse.Query(Follower);
    query.equalTo("following", this.passedUser);
    query.find({
      success: function(follower) {
       for (var i = 0; i < follower.length; i++) {
       this_ref.follows.push(follower[i].get("follower")),
       console.log(this_ref.follows);
       }
        var picture = Parse.Object.extend("Profile")
        var query = new Parse.Query(picture);
        query.containedIn("user", this_ref.follows);
        query.find({
          success: function(picture) {
           for (var i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
           this_ref.pics.push(picture[i].toJSON()),
           console.log(this_ref.pics);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  initializeFollowing() {
    var this_ref = this
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current().get("username");
    var Following = Parse.Object.extend("Follow")
    var query = new Parse.Query(Following);
    query.equalTo("follower", this.passedUser);
    query.find({
      success: function(following) {
       for (var i = 0; i < following.length; i++) {
       this_ref.follows.push(following[i].get("following")),
       console.log(this_ref.follows);
       }
        var picture = Parse.Object.extend("Profile")
        var query = new Parse.Query(picture);
        query.containedIn("user", this_ref.follows);
        query.find({
          success: function(picture) {
           for (var i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
           this_ref.pics.push(picture[i].toJSON()),
           console.log(this_ref.pics);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  viewGuest(pic: string){
    this.navCtrl.push(GuestPage, { userParam: pic})
    console.log(pic);

  }

}
```

Comment: any reason why switch and not `*ngIf`? it would reduce your containers..and what happens with the code? any issues?

Comment: I'll explain what happens in an edit. And I used switch because it wasn't a lot actually being hidden but I can easily change it to if.

Comment: so..what you are trying is if the *loggedIn user* is in the follow list the button should not show.

Comment: Yes the additional code is to see if other users in the listed are followed by the logged in user. I'll get to that later. So for now just to hide for the logged in user

Comment: `this.follows == Parse.User.current().get("username")` doesnt make sense..you are comparing an array with a value?

Comment: actually..you would also need an array of boolean values otherwise it will toggle for the whole list..

Comment: Yeah I realized that after I implemented it. However I did not no where to go from there

Comment: ok..is `pic.user` same as username?

Comment: Correct, the results of the query are in JSON so user is the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.follows == Parse.User.current().get("username")`
Here you are comparing a value with an array which will be false.
What I would do is:

Have a class variable currentUser set in `ionViewWillEnter`

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
  this.currentUser=Parse.User.current().get("username");
}
```

In the Html instead of switch case with value use an if:

```
<div item-right>
      <span *ngIf="pic.user!=currentUser">
        <span [ngSwitch]="connect">
          <span *ngSwitchCase="false"> 
            <button ion-button>Follow</button>
          </span>
          <span *ngSwitchDefault>
            <button ion-button>Following</button>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Also suggest using `*ngIf` instead of the switch case for the other boolean condition as well.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I really appreciate all the help. I'll use this same method for the follow/following thanks a bunch